# Combining continuous dates from two columns in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

```
ID           Order_ID     statr_date            end_date                 Product    Sub_Product 
746              001      08-Oct-2019 0:00:00   *16-Nov-2019 0:00:00*     LPP       Abc
746              002      10-Oct-2019 0:00:00   02-Sep-2020 0:00:00       LPP       Abc
746              003      10-Oct-2019 0:00:00   11-Sep-2020 0:00:00       LPP       Abc
746              004      10-Oct-2019 0:00:00   08-Jan-2021 0:00:00       LPP       Abc
746              005    *16-Nov-2019 0:00:00*   17-Dec-2019 0:00:00       LPP       Abc
```

In the above dataset i want to search for continuous dates, say from the first row having end date 16-nov-2019, look for a continuous date going by the start date and combine them. Such that the final output looks like:

```
  ID         Order_ID     statr_date            end_date                 Product    Sub_Product 
746              001      08-Oct-2019 0:00:00   17-Dec-2019 0:00:00       LPP       Abc
746              002      10-Oct-2019 0:00:00   02-Sep-2020 0:00:00       LPP       Abc
746              003      10-Oct-2019 0:00:00   11-Sep-2020 0:00:00       LPP       Abc
746              004      10-Oct-2019 0:00:00   08-Jan-2021 0:00:00       LPP       Abc
```

How can i go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at each pairwise combination of rows and then compare the start date of one row with the end date of another row to see if they fit the pattern

```py
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations

start_dates = pd.to_datetime(df['statr_date'])
end_dates = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'])
order_ids = df['Order_ID']

dates = [(o, s, e) for o, s, e in zip(order_ids, start_dates, end_dates)]
od_map = dict.fromkeys(order_ids, np.nan)

for combo in combinations(dates, 2):
    ((order_first, start_first, end_first), (order_second, start_second, end_second)) = combo
    if end_first == start_second:
        od_map[order_first] = od_map[order_second] = min(order_first, order_second)

df['od_grp'] = df['Order_ID'].map(od_map).fillna(df['Order_ID'])
df_grp = df.groupby('od_grp').agg({'statr_date': 'min', 'end_date': 'max'})
print(df_grp)
#                 statr_date             end_date
#od_grp                                          
#1.0     08-Oct-2019 0:00:00  17-Dec-2019 0:00:00
#2.0     10-Oct-2019 0:00:00  02-Sep-2020 0:00:00
#3.0     10-Oct-2019 0:00:00  11-Sep-2020 0:00:00
#4.0     10-Oct-2019 0:00:00  08-Jan-2021 0:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try with for-loops and `df.loc[]`

```
for start in df.statr_date:
    for end in df.end_date:
        if start==end:
            df.loc[df[df.end_date.eq(end)].index, 'end_date'] = df.loc[df[df.statr_date.eq(start)].index, 'end_date']
            df = df.drop(df[df.statr_date.eq(start)].index)


Output:
    ID  Order_ID           statr_date             end_date Product Sub_Product
0  746         1  08-Oct-2019 0:00:00  17-Dec-2019 0:00:00     LPP         Abc
1  746         2  10-Oct-2019 0:00:00  02-Sep-2020 0:00:00     LPP         Abc
2  746         3  10-Oct-2019 0:00:00  11-Sep-2020 0:00:00     LPP         Abc
3  746         4  10-Oct-2019 0:00:00  08-Jan-2021 0:00:00     LPP         Abc
```

Edit:
This solution with multiple for-loops won't be very performance-friendly for large data

```
# Input Data
   ID  Order_ID           statr_date             end_date Product Sub_Product
0  746         1  08-Oct-2019 0:00:00  16-Nov-2019 0:00:00     LPP         Abc
1  746         2  10-Oct-2019 0:00:00  02-Sep-2020 0:00:00     LPP         Abc
2  746         3  10-Oct-2019 0:00:00  11-Sep-2020 0:00:00     LPP         Abc
3  746         4  10-Oct-2019 0:00:00  08-Jan-2021 0:00:00     LPP         Abc
4  746         5  16-Nov-2019 0:00:00  17-Dec-2019 0:00:00     LPP         Abc
5  756         6  11-Oct-2019 0:00:00  05-Sep-2020 0:00:00     LBB         Abc
6  756         7  10-Nov-2019 0:00:00  11-Dec-2020 0:00:00     LBB         Abc
7  766         8  22-Oct-2019 0:00:00  19-Nov-2019 0:00:00     LBB         Abc
8  766         9  19-Nov-2019 0:00:00  27-Dec-2019 0:00:00     LBB         Agn


g = df.groupby(['ID','Product', 'Sub_Product'])

dfs = []
for group in g.groups:
    df1 = g.get_group(group)
    for start in df1.statr_date:
        for end in df1.end_date:
            if start==end:
                df1.loc[df1[df1.end_date.eq(end)].index, 'end_date'] = df1.loc[df1[df1.statr_date.eq(start)].index, 'end_date']
                df1 = df1.drop(df1[df1.statr_date.eq(start)].index)
    
    dfs.append(df1)                

out = pd.concat(dfs).reset_index()
out

Output:

   index   ID  Order_ID           statr_date             end_date Product  \
0      0  746         1  08-Oct-2019 0:00:00  17-Dec-2019 0:00:00     LPP   
1      1  746         2  10-Oct-2019 0:00:00  02-Sep-2020 0:00:00     LPP   
2      2  746         3  10-Oct-2019 0:00:00  11-Sep-2020 0:00:00     LPP   
3      3  746         4  10-Oct-2019 0:00:00  08-Jan-2021 0:00:00     LPP   
4      5  756         6  11-Oct-2019 0:00:00  05-Sep-2020 0:00:00     LBB   
5      6  756         7  10-Nov-2019 0:00:00  11-Dec-2020 0:00:00     LBB   
6      7  766         8  22-Oct-2019 0:00:00  19-Nov-2019 0:00:00     LBB   
7      8  766         9  19-Nov-2019 0:00:00  27-Dec-2019 0:00:00     LBB
```

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot. Could you be able to tell me how to modify this code to run for multiple IDs and also when we are looking to club the dates like you did above but by matching the Product and Sub_Product, in the sense that if in the above case if the last row had either a different product or Sub_Product, we wouldn't want to combine them, here we are combining only because the Product and Sub_Product is the same.

Comment: I have made up some data and tried to answer, let me know if I understood correctly

Comment: Will it work for a dataset which has an entry with a unique ID, product and Sub_product along with the above dataset. In the sense that this entry would not have any other entry to compare the dates with? For example, in addition to the above dataset if we were to append another row taking :
ID:800,  Order_ID:22           statr_date:25-Mar-2022       end_date: 31-Mar-2022 Product :LLL       Sub_Product: Aaa

Comment: I tried and it seems to be working. It looks for consecutive dates among rows that have same ID, Product, and Sub_product. So an ID that only appears once will just be returned as it is

Comment: The error while running this code is: "index error: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0". @Yolao_21

Comment: When I am running it, it is not working for me. That kind of an entry is just disappearing from the final output. And when I run it for a much larger dataset, it shows the error mentioned above.

Comment: I have removed `[0]` from `index[0]`. Did you drop rows with NaNs before executing this? Also one entry does disappear, it should be because they have a consecutive date, as the expected output you wanted in the question - or does it disappear evev if there is no consecutive date?

Comment: There were no NaN rows before executing this. 
By removing the [0] from index[0], the end_date which is supposed to show a modified end_date (i.e. after being combined with the consecutive date) shows a NaT value, so i guess we cannot remove [0]. But the row that is supposed to get dropped is getting dropped. The row which is a single entry is also getting dropped. 
Do you know why that is hapenning?