# combine two rows with negligible threshold on a groupby dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a *raw* dataframe(simplified) as below:

| ColumnA | startime | endtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-02-23 08:22:32.113000+00:00 | 2022-02-23 10:54:04.163000+00:00 |
| A | 2022-02-23 10:54:04.163000+00:00 | 2022-02-23 10:54:11.643000+00:00 |
| A | 2022-02-23 10:54:11.643000+00:00 | 2022-02-23 19:56:16.780000+00:00 |

I had to combine the values in a way if startime of next row for an item(in this case only A) is same as(or approx =) the previous end time, we combine the rows. Hence the *result* of the raw table should look like below.

| ColumnA | startime | endtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-02-23 08:22:32.113000+00:00 | 2022-02-23 19:56:16.780000+00:00 |

*Logic for combining start and end date*:
If there are multiple rows for a value(ex. "A") in column A, only combine the rows where start time of next row(i.e startime[i])  == end time of previous row(i.e endtime[i-1]), else keep the start and end time same.

*Sample Input*

| ColumnA | startime | endtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-02-23 08:22:32.113000+00:00 | 2022-02-23 10:30:04.163000+00:00 |
| A | 2022-02-23 10:38:04.163000+00:00 | 2022-02-23 10:54:11.643000+00:00 |
| A | 2022-02-23 10:54:11.643000+00:00 | 2022-02-23 19:56:16.780000+00:00 |

*Sample Output*

| ColumnA | startime | endtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-02-23 08:22:32.113000+00:00 | 2022-02-23 10:30:04.163000+00:00 |
| A | 2022-02-23 10:38:04.163000+00:00 | 2022-02-23 19:56:16.780000+00:00 |

I was able to do the above task via the below code snippet:

```
diffData=[]
for i in range(1, len(dataframe)):
    diffData.append(((dataframe.loc[i,'startime'] - dataframe.loc[i-1,'endtime']).seconds)/60)

dataframe['diff']=[0] + diffData
```

```
def getStartEnd(tempData,THRESHOLD):
    tempData=tempData.reset_index()
    finalData=[]
    startTime=tempData.loc[0,'startime']
    
    for i in range(1,len(tempData)):
        
        if(tempData.loc[i,'diff'] > THRESHOLD):
            finalData.append([tempData.loc[i,'ColumnA'],startTime,tempData.loc[i-1,'endtime']])
            startTime=tempData.loc[i,'startime']
    finalData.append([tempData.loc[i,'ColumnA'],startTime,tempData.loc[i,'endtime']])
    return(pd.DataFrame(finalData,columns=[ColumnA','startime','endtime']))
# Threshold setting to consider the difference "threshold is in seconds"

finalData=pd.DataFrame(columns=['ColumnA','startime','endtime'])
for name in dataframe['ColumnA'].unique():
    print(name)
    finalData=pd.concat([finalData,getStartEnd(dataframe[dataframe['ColumnA']==name],0)])
```

**Question**

Can I seek help in revising the above function(or a new method) to handle a groupby-d dataframe so that for each unique value in ColumnA(ex. A, B, C), I can see similar results.
As of now it **just** works with one value in columnA and not group by dataframe

As of now I am getting the error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment

Sample **Raw** Dataframe looks like below:

| ColumnA | startime | endtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-02-23 08:22:32.113000+00:00 | 2022-02-23 10:23:04.163000+00:00 |
| A | 2022-02-23 10:23:04.163000+00:00 | 2022-02-23 10:54:11.643000+00:00 |
| B | 2022-01-04 17:02:31.343000+00:00 | 2022-01-04 17:20:31.343000+00:00 |
| B | 2022-01-04 17:20:31.343000+00:00 | 2022-01-04 18:12:31.343000+00:00 |

**Expected Output result**

| ColumnA | startime | endtime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-02-23 08:22:32.113000+00:00 | 2022-02-23 10:54:04.163000+00:00 |
| B | 2022-01-04 17:02:31.343000+00:00 | 2022-01-04 18:12:31.343000+00:00 |

Any help is sincerely appreciated. Thank you :)

**Update 1:**

The results from using pairwise from itertools produces duplicate entries on the complete dataset:

```
from more_itertools import pairwise
#df_copy_SD has the same table structure as mentioned but with more number of rows per value.

group_counter = 0
for firstrow, secondrow in pairwise(df_copy_SD.index):
end_first = df_copy_SD.loc[firstrow]['end_timestamp']
start_second = df_copy_SD.loc[secondrow]['start_timestamp']
if end_first == start_second:
df_copy_SD.loc[firstrow, 'group'] = group_counter
df_copy_SD.loc[secondrow, 'group'] = group_counter
else:
group_counter += 1
df_copy_SD.loc[firstrow, 'group'] = group_counter
group_counter += 1
df_copy_SD.loc[secondrow, 'group'] = group_counter

df_grp = df_copy_SD.groupby(['equipment','group']).agg({'start_timestamp': 'min', 'end_timestamp': 'max'})

dfg = pd.DataFrame(df_grp)
```

Comment: Please clarify your logic for combining start and end times.  Based on what you are showing, it looks to me like for each group of [ColumnA] you want a single row containing the earliest start-time and latest end-time for each day.  Is this correct?

Comment: Hi, thank you for asking. To clarify, for each group of [ColumnA] if the endtime of row 1 is  *equal* to startime of row 2, then only we combine, else we keep the row as it is. I have also added a sample I/O example in my question to help you clear things better:)

Comment: This might help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71678475/combining-continuous-dates-from-two-columns-in-pandas-data-frame/71680794#71680794

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at rows pairwise and then compare the start date of one row with the end date of another row to see if they fit the pattern

```py
from itertools import pairwise

print(df)
#  ColumnA                          startime                           endtime
#0       A  2022-02-23 08:22:32.113000+00:00  2022-02-23 10:30:04.163000+00:00
#1       A  2022-02-23 10:38:04.163000+00:00  2022-02-23 10:54:11.643000+00:00
#2       A  2022-02-23 10:54:11.643000+00:00  2022-02-23 19:56:16.780000+00:00

group_counter = 0
for firstrow, secondrow in pairwise(df.index):
    end_first = df.loc[firstrow]['endtime']
    start_second = df.loc[secondrow]['startime']
    if end_first == start_second:
        df.loc[firstrow, 'group'] = group_counter
        df.loc[secondrow, 'group'] = group_counter
    else:
        group_counter += 1
        df.loc[firstrow, 'group'] = group_counter
        group_counter += 1
        df.loc[secondrow, 'group'] = group_counter

df_grp = df.groupby(['ColumnA', 'group']).agg({'startime': 'min', 'endtime': 'max'}).reset_index()

print(df_grp)
#  ColumnA  group                          startime                           #endtime
#0       A    1.0  2022-02-23 08:22:32.113000+00:00  2022-02-23 #10:30:04.163000+00:00
#1       A    2.0  2022-02-23 10:38:04.163000+00:00  2022-02-23 #19:56:16.780000+00:00
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the output is not similar to expected output, I was hoping to see the ColumnA having its values as well and not just group as an index of 0,1,2.

Comment: You can add `ColumnA` to the grouping columns along with the `group` at the last step. I've edited my answer above.

Comment: No, it will contain values from Column A.

Comment: Hi thank you @Mortz for the changes, has been quite helpful, but I am still facing the challenge of duplicated entries per value in ColumnA(mentioned as "equipment" in Update 1 in my question). Is it because of using pairwise ?

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to see the image - could you paste a minimal reproducible example with duplicates as text? Also, please check if there are duplicate rows in your input data.

Comment: I checked and the raw data seems to have duplicates as well, thank you for pointing it out and all the help. Cheers Mate.